# C# precision loss when dividing a double

Tags: c#, precision

The function bellow is passed a string "1004233" and prints the following output:

D1 = 1.004233
D2 = 0.00423299999999993
D3 = 4232.99999999993
D4 = 4232

I need D4 to print 4233 and not 4232.  How do i stop this precision loss from happening?

```
public string someFunc(String s){
        string retval = "0";
        try{
            int id = int.Parse(s);
            double d = (double)id / (double)1000000;
            Console.WriteLine("D1 = " + d);
            d = d - Math.Truncate(d);
            Console.WriteLine("D2 = " + d);
            d = d * (double)1000000;
            Console.WriteLine("D3 = " + d);
            retval = "" + Math.Truncate(d);
            Console.WriteLine("D4 = " + retval);
        }catch(Exception ex){}
        return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [standard floating-point question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Use a `decimal` instead.
Although `decimal`s also don't have infinite precision, they are implemented in base 10, so they will give you the results you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Use [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) arithmetic instead of floating-point (double). More information to be found:

- http://gregs-blog.com/2007/12/10/dot-net-decimal-type-vs-float-type/